# Java ArrayList and Case/Switch?

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

Completely new to Java and I need a little help creating this BookList program :) I have read through my book and im completely confused.  I need to create a arraylist called BookList, I need to display a menu with a case switch that will add a book, edit a book, remove a book and display the books.  I have my program started but it does not work completely It is supposed to display a menu for the user to select from and it will do the following functions but I get an error message with all the Book constructors.  I was hoping some of you Java masters could help a newbie out! This is what I have so far in my BookList class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookList {

public static void main (String[] args){





System.out.println(" =======================================");
    System.out.println("|       1. Add a book                   |");
    System.out.println("|       2. Edit a book                  |");
    System.out.println("|       3. Delete a book                |");
    System.out.println("|       4. Display all books            |");
    System.out.println("|       5. Exit the program             |");
    System.out.println("|  *Type a number to make a selection*  |");
    System.out.println(" =======================================");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Selection: ");

    public static Book()

    {
    int title;
    }
    Book a = new Book();

    a.setTitle("Stranger");


    Book b = new Book();

    b.setTitle("SQL");


    Book c = new Book();

    c.setTitle("HTML");


    ArrayList<Book> BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    BookList.add(a);
    BookList.add(b);
    BookList.add(c);





Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);

int Choice1;

   Choice1 = SC.nextInt();

   SC.close();


    switch (Choice1) {

    case 1:

        Scanner JK = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("'Add a book' selected");
      System.out.println(" ");


      break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("'Edit a book's details' selected");
        System.out.println("Which Book would you like to edit?");
        System.out.println("");
        break;

    case 3:
        System.out.println("'Delete a book' selected");
        break;

    case 4:
          System.out.println("Display all books");
          break;



    case 5:
          System.out.println("Goodbye!");
          System.exit(0);

          break;


    default:
      System.out.println("Invalid selection. Try again");


    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: `but it does not work completely` That isn't a question! What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do? And please format your code a bit better.

Comment: @John3136 I added it!  Its only suppose to display a menu for the user to choose 1-5 from and each number(case) will do a function whether that be too add a book, edit, delete, or display.  The entire constructor Book is getting an error not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `constructor Book is getting an error` And you don't think sharing the error message is relevant?

Comment: @John3136 it says "Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement" ive created  an Enum but I have no idea what to even put in it, ive searched a lot on StackOverFlow and CodeProject but still nothing.

Comment: Why is title an int? Why is it a nested class at all?

Comment: You should add the error to the question rather that put it in the comments. I'm not trying to be an a&^%*le, just trying to show you how to ask a good question that won't be downvoted or closed.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make what I could of it given the question your asked.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookList {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);
        Book a = new Book();

        a.setTitle("Stranger");

        Book b = new Book();
        b.setTitle("SQL");

        Book c = new Book();

        c.setTitle("HTML");

        ArrayList<Book> BookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        BookList.add(a);
        BookList.add(b);
        BookList.add(c);

        int Choice1=1;

        while(Choice1!=5)
        {
            System.out.println(" =======================================");
            System.out.println("|       1. Add a book                   |");
            System.out.println("|       2. Edit a book                  |");
            System.out.println("|       3. Delete a book                |");
            System.out.println("|       4. Display all books            |");
            System.out.println("|       5. Exit the program             |");
            System.out.println("|  *Type a number to make a selection*  |");
            System.out.println(" =======================================");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Selection: ");

            Choice1 = SC.nextInt();

            switch (Choice1) {

                case 1:

                System.out.println("'Add a book' ");
                System.out.println("Enter the name ");
                Book holder = new Book(SC.next());

                break;
                case 2:
                System.out.println("'Edit a book's details' selected");
                System.out.println("Which Book would you like to edit?");
                System.out.println("");

                // I do not understand what you want me to do here

                break;

                case 3:
                for(int i=0;i<BookList.size();i++){
                    System.out.println(i+1+") "+BookList.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Choose a book to delete: ");
                BookList.remove(SC.nextInt()-1);
                break;

                case 4:
                System.out.println("Display all books");
                for(Book x:BookList)
                    System.out.println(x);
                break;


                case 5:
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);

                break;

                default:
                System.out.println("Invalid selection. Try again");

            }
        }
    }
}











public class Book{

    String Title;


    public Book()
    {
        Title="";
    }

    public Book(String bookTitle)
    {
        Title=bookTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String bookTitle)
    {
        Title=bookTitle;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Book Name "+Title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code appears to be attempting to define a constructor within the `main` method.

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    [...]

    public static Book()

    {
    int title;
    }
    Book a = new Book();
```

The constructor needs to be directly within the class. Also it should not have a `static` modifier. It looks like the `title` local should be a field (outside of any methods) of type `String`.

```
private String title;

public Book() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    [...]

    Book a = new Book();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

The Book class isn't declared correctly. Try putting the declaration outside of the BookList class block.

```
public class BookList{
  [...]
}

public class Book{  

    public void setTitle(String newTitle){
      title = newTitle;
    }

    private int title;
}
```

Note that the default constructor for Book is implied, and that you'll have to add a getter for title if you want to use it later.